# No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64) Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

When I update to Xcode 12 beta 5, I can't build my project as usually. It's normal with Xcode 11.6 and Xcode 12 beta 4.

```
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64)
```

Does someone facing the same issue?

Comment: Search for `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` in Build Settings and set it to `NO`. I'm not sure if this will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "build settings" go to "User-Defined->VALID_ARCHS" and add x86_64.

Comment: In "build settings" -> "User-Defined", delete "VALID_ARCHS", it works too.

Answer (score 2):

1, Target -> "Build settings" -> "User-Defined" -> "VALID_ARCHS" and add "x86_64", it works.

2, Target -> "Build settings" -> "User-Defined", delete "VALID_ARCHS", it works too.

Because Xcode 12 has eliminated "VALID_ARCHS".

Comment: For me,  `Target -> "Build settings" -> "User-Defined", delete "VALID_ARCHS"` works. You saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 11.6 Set empty value for Vaild Architectures

Then open it on Xcode 12 / Xcode 12 beta 5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding x86_64 along with arm64 separated by a space to the VALID_ARCHS item.

[image]